# SceneKit - Rotate object around X and Z axis

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, scenekit, arkit

I’m using ARKit with SceneKit. When user presses a button I create an anchor and to the SCNNode corresponding to it I add a 3D object (loaded from a .scn file in the project).

The 3D object is placed facing the camera, with the same orientation the camera has. I would like to make it look like the object is laying on a plane surface and not inclined if it is that way. So, if I got it right, I’d need to apply a rotation transformation so that it’s rotation around the X and Z axis become 0.

My attempt at this is: take the node’s x and z eulerAngles, invert them, and rotate that amount around each axis

```swift
let rotationZ = rotationMatrixAroundZ(radians: -node.eulerAngles.z)
let rotationX = rotationMatrixAroundX(radians: -node.eulerAngles.x) 

let rotationTransform = simd_mul(rotationTransformX, rotationTransformZ)
node.transform = SCNMatrix4(simd_mul(simd_float4x4(node.transform), rotationTransform))
```

This works all right for most cases, but in some  the object is rotated in completely strange ways. Should I be setting the
rotation angle to anything else than just the inverse of the current Euler Angle? Setting the angles to 0 directly did not work at all.

Comment: Do you use constraints?

Comment: No, I tried experimenting with the SCNLookAtConstraint and the look(at:) method, but none of them was satisfying my needs

Comment: could you post the function of rotationMatrixAroundZ() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've come across this and figured out I was running into [gimbal lock](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/469/could-someone-please-explain-gimbal-lock). The solution was to rotate the node around one axis, parent it to another `SCNNode()`, then rotate the parent around the other axis. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I figured I was running in to gimbal lock, but hadn't thought of this way to solve it!

Comment: This is a brilliant solution! I [made a wrapper class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58470230/35690) so that it's easy to apply all 3 rotations on any node.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do the node transform on a matrix, you can simply rotate around a specific axis and that might be a bit simpler in terms of the logic of doing the rotation.

You could do something like:

```
node.runAction(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: x, y: y, z: z, duration: 0.0))
```

Not sure if this is the kind of thing you're looking for, but it is simpler than doing the rotation with the SCNMatrix4

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, hadn't explored this option. I'll try it!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I managed a workaround, but I'm not truly happy with it, so I'll leave the question unanswered. Basically I define a threshold of 2 degrees and keep applying those rotations until both Euler Angles around X and Z are below the aforementioned threshold.

```swift
func layDownNode(_ node: SCNNode) {
    let maxErrDegrees: Float = 2.0
    let maxErrRadians = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(maxErrDegrees)

    while (abs(node.eulerAngles.x) > maxErrRadians || abs(node.eulerAngles.z) > maxErrRadians) {
        let rotationZ = -node.eulerAngles.z
        let rotationX = -node.eulerAngles.x

        let rotationTransformZ = rotationMatrixAroundZ(radians: rotationZ)
        let rotationTransformX = rotationMatrixAroundX(radians: rotationX)

        let rotationTransform = simd_mul(rotationTransformX, rotationTransformZ)

        node.transform = SCNMatrix4(simd_mul(simd_float4x4(node.transform), rotationTransform))
    }
}
```